# How to create an x-pkcs7-signature s/mime message?

Tags: c#, pkcs#7, smime

I am trying to create x-pkcs7-signature s/mime messages in C#. I've been experimenting with Mimekit and can only make pkcs7 messages.

Does anyone know what I need to do to create x-pkcs messages or point me to some examples?

Regards

Comment: FWIW, `application/x-pkcs7-mime` and `application/x-pkcs7-signature` were used before S/MIME became a standard back in the 90's. The official mime-types are now (and have been for over 2 decades) `application/pkcs7-mime` and `application/pkcs7-signature`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways to sign a message using S/MIME:

1. `application/[x-]pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data`
2. `application/[x-]pkcs7-signature`

To sign the first way, do this:

```
var signer = new MailboxAddress ("", "signer@example.com");
var signed = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Sign (signer, DigestAlgorithm.Sha256, entity);
```

The other way is done like this:

```
using (var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext ()) {
    var signer = new MailboxAddress ("", "signer@example.com");
    var signed = MultipartSigned.Sign (ctx, signer, DigestAlgorithm.Sha256, entity);
}
```

In both cases, you can also use a `MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsSigner` instead of a `MailboxAddress`. You could also use a `SecureMailboxAddress` if you know the fingerprint of the certificate.